Запуск консольной команды только через обертку в linux
Есть некая программа (пусть будет pt-archiver), и не хочется давать ей пользоваться от php напрямую. А через какой-нить shell скрипт что будет вызывать pt-archiver и требовать пароль. При этом pt-archiver нельзя будет запустить ниоткуда, кроме как через этот shell скрипт. Как это можно реализовать?

Можно создать отдельного пользователя, который единственный будет иметь права на запуск нужной программы. При запуске (sudo -u ...) будет запрошен пароль пользователя.

Предлагаю упаковать pt-archiver в докер. Тогда только пользователи из группы docker смогут запускать контейнер. И его нельзя будет запустить никак иначе, кроме как через контейнер. Пользователю php разрешить доступ через sudo docker start ... pt-archiver-container с конкретными прописанными наборами параметров.
